# How can I create a mailchimp campaign using tags?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'd like to create a mailchimp campaign for a subsets of an email list by filtering the list on a tag ('test_tag') that I've applied to the intended subset. I'm not sure what the correct syntax is for this. I can't find any documentation on how to programmatically create anything using tags.

I can successfully achieve emailing the subset of my list using the 'prebuilt_segment_id' feature. I created a segment called 'test_segment'.

The following code works:

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns' \
--user 'anystring:12345667889qwerty' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"recipients":{"list_id":"123abc", "segment_opts":{"prebuilt_segment_id":"test_segment"}},"type":"regular","settings":{"subject_line":"Your Purchase Receipt", "reply_to":"orders@mammothhouse.com","from_name":"Customer Service"}}' \
--include
```

What would the syntax be for using my tag 'test_tag' instead of my segment (assume that every member in the 'test_segment' has the tag of 'test_tag')?

The following code does not work:

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns' \
--user 'anystring:12345667889qwerty' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"recipients":{"list_id":"123abc", "segment_opts":{"conditions":[ { "condition_type":"Tag", "field":"tag", "op":"is", "value":"test_tag" }]},"type":"regular","settings":{"subject_line":"Your Purchase Receipt", "reply_to":"orders@mammothhouse.com","from_name":"Customer Service"}}' \
--include
```

Any help with this or any examples of using tags to create something using the api would be much appreciated (eg, can I create a segment using tags?)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/alternative-schemas/#segment-condition-schemas) (see StaticSegment), **StaticSegments** are now **Tags**, so here's the proper way to create your **conditions** array when you want to segment by tag:

```
    'conditions' => [
        [
          'condition_type' => 'StaticSegment',
          'field' => 'static_segment',
          'op' => 'static_is',
          'value' => $tagId
        ]
     ]
```

Keep in mind that you need to get the tag id in advance in order for this to work. There is API in the docs on how to do it.